# Calculate Time Elapsed Between Records

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
pageload  
--pageloadid (autoincrementing numeric id field)
--BeginDateTime
```

Now I'd like to show all records and show the time elapsed between every record. I can add another field to my table to store an EndDateTime if necessary but I'm guessing there is some simple way to do this in SQL that I'm just not thinking of.

I'm currently using MS Access but the solution you suggest should be database agnostic, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to create database-agnostic query in this case:

However this query will work in both MS Access and MS SQL Server:

```
select p1.pageloadid, datediff("s", p1.BeginDateTime, p2.BeginDateTime)
from pageload p1, pageload p2
where 
    p1.pageloadid < p2.pageloadid and
    not exists(select * from pageload p3 where p3.pageloadid > p1.pageloadid and p3.pageloadid < p2.pageloadid)
```

The query will show the diff time in seconds between two adjacent rows (if ordered by `pageloadid`).

I suggest you adding `EndDateTime` as this will simplify and expedite the query significantly.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a database agnostic way to do this, if you're talking about without Access, time & date functions vary from vendor to vendor.

However, Access supports datediff, and the MS implementation takes a interval as the first parameter. See http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php